# Getting Json to go into array php

Tags: php

I've spent ages searching through the internet however I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

```
$follow = $_GET['follow'];
$following = $_GET['following'];

session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('MY PRIVATE CODE', 'MY PRIVATE CODE', $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_secret']);
}

$follow_timeline = $twitteroauth->get('followers/ids', array('screen_name' => $follow));
$following_timeline = $twitteroauth->get('friends/ids', array('screen_name' =>     $following));

if (in_array($following, $follow_timeline)) {
echo "We found the word!";
}
```

It the data it from a json file. You can also read this. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids & https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids. It displays this error when I run the script written above.

```
in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in
```

And I thought about using json decode before the `if (in_array($following, $follow_timeline))` but it then displays this error.

```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
```

Please can someone help. I just got started with php and I found it a bit confusing.

Comment: Ìt's completely unclear what your problem is. First problem: What is the content of the var `$follow_timeline`? Second problem: How do you use json_decode()? Seems like `$follow_timeline` is an object you have to properly use. It is not an array, it is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You define `$following_timeline`, but then your try to use `$follow_timeline`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for in_array() ....http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

The second parameter ($follow_timeline) should be an array... are you sure that the $twitteroauth->get() method returns an array?

Comment: The json coming in from the web service would be a string, so you would want to wrap it in a json_decode() call to turn it into a PHP Array. Also pass in true as 2nd parameter to json_decode to make it an array (instead of object). example: json_decode($follow_timeline, true);